# Azure oAuth getting HTML body instead of code from Angular get request

Tags: angular, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I'm just doing the simple get request for authorize end point like below, but getting a HTML response in body, but I expect the code in redirect URI so that I can use this code to get the token. I'm making this get request in Angular app

```
getAuth() {
return this.http.get('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=0b59aafg-786c-425a-b2b4-l3f1e9e0d09g
&scope=openid+profile+email
&response_mode=query
&redirect_uri=https://qwe1124/logentry/log-entry/#/', { responseType: 'text', observe: 'response' });
  }
```

Below is the response sample
body: "
↵
↵<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All "
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 4

Please help me on this ..

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1):

First to say, auth code grant flow is an interactive authentication, it is interactive login(by user) required. So if you use get request to the url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`, it will response the html of the login page.

To implement auth code grant flow, you need to use a pop-up window for authenticating. I find a code sample provided below for your reference:

```
this.authWindow = new BrowserWindow(
    {
        alwaysOnTop : true, // keeps this window on top of others
        webPreferences : {
            nodeIntegration  : false, // again, don't need to specify these if Electron v4+ but showing for demo
            contextIsolation : true // we can isolate this window
        }
    }
);

this.authWindow.on('closed', () => {
    this.authWindow = null;
});

authWindow.loadURL(`
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/${config.auth.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
        client_id=xxxxxxx
        &response_type=code
        &redirect_uri=xxxxxxx
        &response_mode=query
        &scope=xxxxxxx
`);
```

In the new browser window, you need to login for authenticating.

Then we need to listen for when it has returned with query parameters in the URL, which contain `?code=` and will have the granted code for obtaining access token. You can refer to the code sample below:

```
authWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    session.defaultSession.webRequest.onCompleted({ urls: [`{redirect_uri}/?code=` + '*'] }, details => {
        const _url        = details.url.split('?')[1]; // get the equivalent of window.location.search for the URLSearchParams to work properly
        const _params     = new URLSearchParams(_url);
        const _accessCode = _params.get('code');

        if (_accessCode) {
            const tokenRequestUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${config.auth.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

            const tokenRequestBody = {
                grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
                client_id     : xxxxxxx,
                code          : _accessCode,
                redirect_uri  : xxxxxxx,
                scope         : xxxxxxx,
                client_secret : xxxxxxx     //Only required for web apps
            };

            request.post(
                { url: tokenRequestUrl, form: tokenRequestBody },
                (err, httpResponse, body) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('Token Received!\n', body);
                    } else {
                        // Probably throw an error? 
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
          // Probably throw an error?   
        }
    });
});
```

After that, you can get the access token in the `body` of above code(in `console.log('Token Received!\n', body);` above)